# Plotting multidimensional binary data as horizontal bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to nicely plot a multidimensional array (see below) as parallel horizontal bars, in a way that it's filled when `True` and white when `False`.

Here's my data:

```
    bar_1  bar_2   bar_3
0    True  False   False
1    True  False   False
2    True  False    True
3   False   True   False
4   False   True   False
5   False   True   False
6   False  False   False
7   False  False   False
8   False  False   False
9   False   True   False
10  False   True   False
11  False   True   False
12  False   True   False
13  False   True   False
14  False   True   False
15  False   True   False
16   True  False   False
17   True  False   False
18   True  False    True
19  False   True   False
20  False   True   False
21  False   True   False
22   True  False    True
23  False   True   False
24  False   True   False
25  False   True   False
```

Here's how I'd like to display it:

[image]

I was looking through the matplotlib docs for something similar, but no luck. Perhaps I'm missing the keywords for this type of plotting. What'd be the name of this type of plot? Is it possible to generate this with matplotlib?

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking for someone to provide the code to do what you want? What you describe here is a task, not a problem. The general consensus on SO is that questions need to have a clear problem description (What have you tried to produce the desired result? In how far did it fail? What resources did you use and in how have they helped or not?). See [ask]. You would start at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_barh.html) and try to bring your data in a useful shape. If you then encounter a problem, ask for help with it.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to ask the actual question. Thanks for the tip, looking into it.

Comment: Such plots are often referred to as [Gantt-charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart). There are already [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Gantt+chart+%5Bmatplotlib%5D) about those on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) I came up with a solution. I am going to use [broken_barh](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.broken_barh.html) which was not exactly designed for this purpose, but with a little bit of tweaking, it can be used for this.
For the sake of simplicity, I'll only display a function, and mark the places red where it's above 0.5.

```
index = np.linspace(start=-1, stop=5, num=100)
sin = np.sin(index**2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'sin': sin, 'filtered': sin > .5}, index=index)
```

Produces

[image: Binary looks awful plotted as normal values]

**Note** I'm not going to use the same data as on the plots because that'd take up too much space

In the next step, I compute the flag points where my function crosses the threshold. Just to visualize it:

```
0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0
```

I compute the shifted values:

```
0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  // The original values
0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0
```

And I keep only the values where the original array is `True` and the other two arrays `xor` (either one is `True` or the other but not both):

```
0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

**Note** that a single spike that doesn't cross just touches the threshold will be 0.

This can be easily achieved with

```
flags = df.filtered & (df.filtered.shift().fillna(False) ^ df.filtered.shift(-1).fillna(False))
```

Now I multiply the flag points with the index (not necessarily an integer index).

```
flag_values = flags * flags.index

0  0  0  3  0  5  0  0  8  9  0  0  0  0  0
```

And drop the 0 values:

```
flag_values = flag_values[flag_values != 0]

[3, 5, 8, 9]
```

I still need to reshape it:

```
value_pairs = flag_values.values.reshape((-1, 2))

[[3, 5],
 [8, 9]]
```

And now I need to subtract the first column from the second one:

```
value_pairs[:, 1] = value_pairs[:, 1] - value_pairs[:, 0]
```

And I can plot it as follows:

```
ax = df.sin.plot()
// The second parameter is the height of the bar, and its thickness.
ax.broken_barh(value_pairs, (0.49, 0.02,), facecolors='red')
```

Here's the result

[image]